# getName() on new thread returns 'main'

Tags: android, android-log, android-thread

I initialize and run a new thread in `onCreate()` in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// ... code

// New thread
new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            // Output is 'TAG: main'
            Log.v("TAG",Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }.run();
}
```

Why is the output of this line `TAG: main`?

```
// Output is 'TAG: main'
Log.v("TAG",Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Isn't this thread supposed to be a new thread?

If I stick an infinite `while` loop into the thread, my app locks up, indicating that this new thread is indeed the main thread.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// ... code

// New thread
new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            // Output is 'TAG: main'
            Log.v("TAG",Thread.currentThread().getName());

            // Locks up the main thread apparently
            while(true) {}
        }
    }.run();
}
```

I just don't get. Am I not creating a new thread and why?

Comment: Use `start()`, not `run()`.

Comment: @MikeM. OMG THANK YOU. Will check mark you if you answer.

Comment: Oh, I just closed it as a duplicate, actually. Thanks, though. :-) Glad you got it working. Cheers!